# Pygame - getting a sprite to cycle through images in a class, and assign a hitbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pygame

TLDR; Code is below

I'm so done with pygame I'm just so confused, 
like I guess I am learning more about classes, and loops and everything but, I think we bit off more than we can chew in this school project for just a few days of working on together (in-person). Going to school for Full Stacks Dev, and this is the first project they have us doing and I learn a lot from you on stackoverflow, but you give complex answers and we get them working but I guess i'm learning a lot about debugging.

Anyways, reason for so many pygame related questions for sure don't wanna be a pygame expert...

Zombie Code:

```
import pygame
import random
import math
# import fighting_game

# Player = player()




class ZombieEnemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
# zwalkRight = [pygame.image.load('images/zombiestandright1.png'), pygame.image.load('images/ztep.png'), pygame.image.load('imageszombiestandright1.png'), pygame.image.load('images/zombiestandright1.png')]

# zwalkLeft = [(pygame.image.load('images/zombiestandleft.png'), pygame.image.load('images/ztepleft.png'), pygame.image.load('images/zombiestandleft.png'), pygame.image.load('images/ztep2.png')]
    def __init__(self, x=300, y=360):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/zombie.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)
    def move_towards_player(self, player):
        # Find direction vector (dx, dy) between enemy and player.
        dx, dy = player.rect.x - self.rect.x, player.rect.y - self.rect.y
        dist = math.hypot (dx, dy)
        dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist # Normalize
        # Move along this normalized vector towards the player
        self.rect.x += dx * 10
        self.rect.y += dy * 0
```

Main Code:

```
import pygame
import math
import random
from Zombie import *
# from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((900,567))

pygame.display.set_caption("Power Rangers ZOMBIES")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('images/walk1.png'), pygame.image.load('images/walk2.png'), pygame.image.load('images/walk3.png'), pygame.image.load('images/walk4.png'), pygame.image.load('images/walk5.png'), pygame.image.load('images/walk6.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('images/leftwalk2.png'), pygame.image.load('images/leftwalk3.png'), pygame.image.load('images/leftwalk4.png'), pygame.image.load('images/leftwalk5.png'), pygame.image.load('images/leftwalk6.png'), pygame.image.load('images/leftwalk7.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('images/background.png')
char = pygame.image.load('images/standingstill.png')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((144,200))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 0
        self.isJump = False
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 18:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if self.left:
            win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.right:
            win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount +=1
        else:
            win.blit(char, (self.x,self.y))

class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  #call Sprite initializer
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/background.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location

BackGround = Background('images/background.png', [0,0])

# def redrawGameWindow():
#     win.blit(bg, (0,0))
#     man.draw(win)

#     pygame.display.update()
all_zombies = pygame.sprite.Group()





#mainloop
man = Player(100, 340, 40, 60)
run = True
for i in range( 50 ):
    new_x = random.randrange( 0, 10000)       # random x-position
    # new_y = random.randrange( 0, )      # random y-position
    z = ZombieEnemy(new_x)
    all_zombies.add(z)         # create, and add to group
    z.move_towards_player(man)

    #####
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel:
        BackGround.rect.left = BackGround.rect.left + int(10)
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]: #and man.x < 500 - man.width - man.vel:
        BackGround.rect.left = BackGround.rect.left - int(10)
        man.x += man.vel
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
    else:
        man.right = False
        man.left = False
        man.walkCount = 0

    if not(man.isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            man.isJump = True
            man.right = False
            man.left = False
            man.walkCount = 0
    else:
        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            man.jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man.isJump = False
            man.jumpCount = 10

    # redrawGameWindow()
    for zombie in all_zombies:
        zombie.move_towards_player(man)

    win.blit(BackGround.image, BackGround.rect)
    all_zombies.update()
    man.draw(win)
    all_zombies.draw(win)
    pygame.display.flip()


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: @APhillips Oh we where given those so tutorials, but we're already in neck deep. lol... But it looks nice if anything we will flop the game over into being a zombie collector with a score counter.. but we got about two and half more days to work on it so..

Comment: describe problem. I see you aready cicle images in Player.draw().

Comment: BTW: in Player you could use in all places `man.rect.x` , `man.rect.y` instead of `man.x` `man.y`, and `self.rect` instead of `(self.x, self.y)` in `win.blit(..., self.rect)`. And then you can use `man.rect` as hitbox and check collision `man.rect.colliderect(zombie.rect)` or [pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(man, all_zombies)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany)

Comment: @furas I'm trying to do this in the zombie, so the enemy that goes to the player flips through images, and has a hitbox. Also will try to get the hitbox set up the player working. Does slack have a messanger can you just message me? Because you've helped me a ton.

Comment: Would like to add my eyeballs burn and i'm super tired so I'll probably get back started on this early in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The player (`man`) is a [`Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and the all the zombies are in the [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) `all_zombies`.
Use [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) to finde collisions between a zombie and the player. e.g.:

```py
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(man, all_zombies, False):
    print("hit")
```

To make that work you have to track the position oft the player in the `.rect` attribute., because that is used by `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` to finde the collisions.
You don't need the attributes `.x` and `.y` at all. e.g.:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        # [...]

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 18:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if self.left:
            win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//3], (self.rect.x,self.rect.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.right:
            win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//3], (self.rect.x,self.rect.y))
            self.walkCount +=1
        else:
            win.blit(char, (self.rect.x,self.rect.y))
```

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.rect.x > man.vel:
        BackGround.rect.left = BackGround.rect.left + int(10)
        man.rect.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]: #and man.x < 500 - man.width - man.vel:
        BackGround.rect.left = BackGround.rect.left - int(10)
        man.rect.x += man.vel
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
    else:
        man.right = False
        man.left = False
        man.walkCount = 0
```

Comment: Okay sweet, got it printing hit in console whenever the zombies are on top of the player, and cleaned up the code a bit.

Comment: But how do I implement my zombies sprites switching between images in my classes like that ? The way I have them moving towards the player. Probably some big long while loop or is their a shorter method.

Comment: @Blue *"how do I implement my zombies sprites switching between images"* - What do you mean by "switching between images"?

Comment: Like say the animations, I have it commented out in the Zombie file. if you notice, how I implement that into the way classes are setup, sorry I had worded that a little weird.